# sorting the list inside another list

Tags: python

I have a list like this `b=['4 2 1 3 5']`.
I want to sort by number but unable to do so. I want my final result to be `b=['1 2 3 4 5']`

Comment: `b=['4 2 1 3 5']` contains a single element, which is a string.

Comment: ['4 2 1 3 5'] is representing a string inside a list, not a list inside another list.

Comment: What are you actually doing?

Comment: Could you add more samples? Do the list contains more strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to sort a *string* inside a list, not a list inside a list. Oh well, here's one possibility:

```
b = ['4 2 1 3 5']
b = [' '.join(sorted(b[0].split(), key=int))]
```

Now `b` equals:

```
['1 2 3 4 5']
```

Comment: Your code will not work in case b = ['44 41 42 4 5'] ... it will return ['4 41 42 44 5'] then ...

Comment: @Idlehands Can you point out what you mean with key=int? I normally use the way I used in my answer `[int(x) for x in subLst.split(" ")]`. However if there is an easier way, I would like to know it / would be interested ;)

Comment: It's specific to @oscarlopez's answer, where you can use `sorted(b[0].split(), key=int)` to sort the elements by first converting them to int.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will work when there are multiple sublists in the list. Furthermore it will also work if there are not just one digest numbers (like ['4 41 42 44 5']):

```
b = ['4 2 1 3 5', '8 9 1 2 3']
b = [" ".join([str(x) for x in sorted([int(x) for x in subLst.split(" ")])]) for subLst in b]
print(b)
```